# How to get data from many-to-many relationship builded by Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, many-to-many

I made many-to-many relationship from [this tutorial](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-ef-core.aspx)

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IList<StudentCourse> StudentCourses { get; set; }
}

public class Course
{
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public string CourseName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public IList<StudentCourse> StudentCourses { get; set; }
}

public class StudentCourse
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public Student Student { get; set; }

    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public Course Course { get; set; }
}
```

How i can take Courses list by StudentID?

How it convert to `IQueryable<Student>` (need for asp.net)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If all you want to do is get all the courses that a student is taking there are multiple ways to go about this.
I am guessing you have a `DbSet<StudentCourse> StudentCourses` entry in your database context.
You could simply call `context.StudentCourses.Include(x => x.Student).Where(entry => entry.CourseId == theIdYouWant).Select(entry => entry.Student)`.

Note the `.Include()` which tells Entity Framework to "join" the student table with the StudentCourse table so you will get the actual student entities instead of just the ids (if you left the include out it is very likely the student property would just be set to null)

Comment: The `Include` is't necessary, it's even ignored. Why would `Student` be null if it's explicitly selected?

Comment: I have now way of fact checking this right now, but this is how it works in the ef core version I am using

Comment: Yeah, it works, but it's not necessary. It would be nice to test such things before posting an answer. There's not such a thing as "likely" in deterministic software. It is, or it isn't.

Comment: Is still argue that it adds clarity whether it is necessary or not but this comes down to personal preference. I will try to add more details to future answeres but this was written at 1am.

Comment: I disagree. Adding no-op code only causes confusion. It contributes to the wide-spread misconception that `Include` is necessary to make projections work. As for clarity, `Select(entry => entry.Student)` is clear enough, esp. since it's the only part that determines the output.